# Update/Insert sqlite db via listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of data input by user that needed to be updated into sqlite. Most of the example is just shown update database by just using OnItemClick, what i want is to update the entire list of data into database. Hope someone can help.
Thanks.

Set adapter into listview

```
private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new NewRowAdapter(this, R.layout.new_row_list_item, new ArrayList<NewRow>());
    ListView NewRowListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.NewRowList);
    NewRowListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

This is the Button click for Adding new row in listview.

```
private void setupAddRowBtn() {
    findViewById(R.id.AddRow).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.insert(new AddRow("", 0, 0), 0);                

        }
    });
}
```

My adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    NewRowHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new NewRowHolder();
    holder.NewRow = items.get(position);
    holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Row_name);
    setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
    holder.name.setEnabled(false);
    holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Row_value);
    holder.value.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    setValueTextListeners(holder);
    holder.value2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Row_value2);
    holder.value2.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);
    setValue2TextListeners(holder);

    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}
```

Comment: try calling notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter whenever you add a row.

Comment: is updated once I pressed. What I want is to update the new changed data from the listview into my sqlite db by pressing a submit button.

Comment: on the submit button, iterate through your whole list, updating the database as you go.

Comment: thx @Keale i got what i want...